# How do I get all routes of the current module?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

If I have this for example in my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'overviews', loadChildren: './pages/overviews/overviews.module#OverviewsPageModule' },
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in my overviews component I got this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: OverviewsPage },
  { path: 'childRoute1', loadChildren: './pages/overviews/childRoute1/childRoute1.module#ChildRoute1PageModule' },
  { path: 'childRoute2', loadChildren: './pages/overviews/childRoute2/childRoute2.module#ChildRoute2PageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [OverviewsPage]
})
export class OverviewsPageModule {}
```

How can I get all my childroutes (ChildRoute1, ChildRoute2, ..) within `overviews`?

I know I can get all routes (from app.routes.module) with this:

```
export class OverviewsPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.config); // Gives all routes
  }
```

But I don't want that. I only want the routes of the current module when I'm in `overviews`.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-i17ztz

On the /button page you can see my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the children as follows,

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
    console.log(event.state.root.firstChild);
 }
});
```

Comment: That gives undefined, because they are not defined as the children of overviews. They are just being lazyloaded.

Comment: That doesn't return anything to me

Comment: oh try to tweak a little bit and see. print root and then access rest

Comment: Only place I can find it in is _loadedChildren.routes but I can't access that the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information about childerns route using -

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof ChildActivationEnd) {
        console.log(event.snapshot.routeConfig.children);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I can see it in `routeConfig._loadedChildren.routes` which I don't know how to access but routeConfig.children gives me undefined.

Comment: @SinanSamet I have tested this on my local machine, and is working fine, can you confirm if you are using this source code in the root component's (`overviews` in your case) controller side?

Comment: Yes I am, I will try to reproduce the problem in stackblitz when I got the time

Comment: I added a stackblitz which exactly simulates my problem. It also tells me that `children` does not exist on null. I'm sure it's something I'm forgetting if it works on your machine but I'm not sure what it is.